# How to change Windows 10 Event Log level (brevity)

Tags: windows, windows-10, logging

I have multiple applications and services cluttering my Windows Application Log. For example, SanDisk SSD Dashboard Service (installed automatically through windows update) writes

> SanDisk SSD Dashboard Service. Number of supported device: 2

Message mutliple times a minute.

Same with many other log sources, such as ESENT:

> svchost (3332,G,0) The beta feature EseDiskFlushConsistency is enabled in ESENT due to the beta site mode settings 0x800000.

(Again multiple times a minute)

I find it unnecessary and would like to disable logging of information events altogether. (Obviously, I'm not going to chase every single program doing this).

I do **not** want to just filter displayed messages in the Event Viewer.

---

I found this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687437.aspx

> To disable logging for a specific event
>   1. In the Application Center snap-in, expand the cluster node.
>   ...

However, have no `Application Center snap-in` in my mmc.

I tried exploring Event Viewer options, but bound no relevant ones.

Tried to search for a relevant Group Policy setting, again with no success.

---

Is there a way of disabling logging of `info` level log events in Windows 10?

Comment: Application Center isn't supported.  The article you linked to does not apply to Windows 10 or any supported version of Windows. [Please note that Application Center has reached the end of mainstream support. However, free extended support has been offered to all Application Center customers.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545877.aspx).  It is a feature of Windows 2000 and SP2 added support for Windows Server 2003.  You are using neither.

Comment: Thanks. I did not realise the context of that article.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/8339/how-can-i-remove-specific-events-from-the-event-log-in-windows-server-2008 As far as I can tell you need to configure each application that generates the events where/if possible.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful link. Unfortunately configuring applications doesn't sound feasible (or even possible) though.